# Configuring SqlCacheDependency with aspnet_regsql

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm trying to prepare my database for use with SQLCacheDependency and using the aspnet_regsql utility to setup the aspnet change notification table and appropriate triggers.

When I run the following:

```
aspnet_regsql -S PC199 -E -d mydatabase -ed
```

I get the error: 'The argument '-S' is invalid.'

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and .NET 4.

Answer (score 1):

The -S argument should be a valid argument to identify the server that hosts the database you want to run the command against.  Not completely sure but you might need to add ".exe" to the end of the command name like so:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S localhost -E -ed -d Northwind -et -t Employees
```

You can find more info about aspnet_regsql.exe here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx